# Breaking a string in C with multiple spaces

Tags: c, loops, whitespace

Ok, so my code currently splits a single string like this: "hello world" into:

```
hello
world
```

But when I have multiple spaces in between, before or after within the string, my code doesn't behave. It takes that space and counts it as a word/number to be analyzed. For example, if I put in two spaces in between hello and world my code would produce:

```
hello
(a space character)
world
```

The space is actually counted as a word/token.

```
int counter = 0;
int index = strcur->current_index;
char *string = strcur->myString;

char token_buffer = string[index];

while(strcur->current_index <= strcur->end_index)
{
    counter = 0;
    token_buffer = string[counter+index];
    while(!is_delimiter(token_buffer) && (index+counter)<=strcur->end_index)//delimiters are: '\0','\n','\r',' '
    {
        counter++;
        token_buffer = string[index+counter];
    }

    char *output_token = malloc(counter+1);
    strncpy(output_token,string+index,counter);
    printf("%s \n", output_token);
    TKProcessing(output_token);

    //update information
    counter++;    
    strcur->current_index += counter;
    index += counter;
}
```

I can see the problem area in my loop, but I'm a bit stumped as to how to fix this. Any help would be must appreciated.

Comment: Instead of a single `counter++` after reading a word, use your `is_delimiter` function there again with a `while` loop.

Comment: add a control `if(counter > 0)` before you do output_token process

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the standard C library function strtok().

Rather than redevelop such a standard function.

Here's the related [related manual page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strtok.3.html).

Can use as following in your case:

```
#include <string.h>
char *token;    

token = strtok (string, " \r\n");
// do something with your first token
while (token != NULL)
{
  // do something with subsequents tokens
  token = strtok (NULL, " \r\n");
}
```

As you can observe, each subsequent call to strtok using the same arguments will send you back a char* adressing to the next token.

In the case you're working on a threaded program, you might use strtok_r() C function.

First call to it should be the same as strtok(), but subsequent calls are done passing NULL as the first argument. :

```
#include <string.h>
char *token;
char *saveptr;

token = strtok_r(string, " \r\n", &saveptr)
// do something with your first token
while (token != NULL)
{
   // do something with subsequents tokens
   token = strtok_r(NULL, " \r\n", &saveptr)
}
```

Comment: Make `do something with your tokenized word` a comment as `//do something with your tokenized word`. Though it doesn't matter much.

Comment: another useful [`strtok`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strtok/) reference

Comment: strtok_r is not standard

Comment: @amdixon Who cares? This is not a requirement.

Comment: There's no gain using strtok_r instead of strtok here.

Comment: @MaximeB You can't know. What if the OP code sample has to be executed by a thread? ...

Comment: @nouney without knowing more on the OPs context i wouldnt assume

Comment: @amdixon Exactly, I would'nt assume that the OP does not use threads :)

Comment: @MaximeB Your code don't work. Please try it before posting it.

Comment: Sorry, but I'm a bit confused how I can fit this into my existing code (still new to C).

Comment: @amdixon By the way, `strtok_r()` is POSIX.1-2001 compliant.

Comment: @Bret just use the first snippet of code, where token is your "word" from the char *string, delimited by " " "\r" and "\n".

Comment: @nouney true this is good solution for posix-compliant systems. and for windows can add an alias to strtok_s

Comment: @Bret If this answer helped, please set it as accepted :)

Answer (score 1):

From a coding stand point, if you wanted to know how to do this without a library as an exercise, what's happening is your loop breaks after you run into the first delimeter. Then when you loop to the second delimeter, you don't enter the second while loop and print a new line again. You can put

```
//update information
while(is_delimiter(token_buffer) && (index+counter)<=strcur->end_index)
{
    counter++;
    token_buffer = string[index+counter];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just put the process token logic into a`if(counter > 0){...}`, which makes `malloc` happen only when there was a real token. like this

```
if(counter > 0){ // it means has a real word, not delimeters 
   char *output_token = malloc(counter+1);
   strncpy(output_token,string+index,counter);
   printf("%s \n", output_token);
   TKProcessing(output_token);
}
```